# Selenium Webdriver with Java to test Python applications

Tags: java, python, selenium

I wanna know that,can we test website that is built on python using selenium with java?

Comment: In your subject you say "python application", but in the question you say "website that is built on python." Webdriver can easily be used to test a website, regardless of what is running on the backend. Testing a Python application (with a GUI I assume?) could be a lot more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that sounds feasible. ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

Answer (score 0):

of course you can. the language the server was written with has nothing to do with the language you use is your web automation project.